# How can I execute SQL and get results from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code

```
  $tnid = mysql_query("SELECT TrainingID FROM training ORDER BY TrainingID DESC LIMIT 1");
```

the query above will return the last row from training table. 
If i echo $tnid it will show 'Resource id #5'.
And if i add

```
    $d = mysql_fetch_array($tnid);
```

then i echo $d, it will show an error message

> Array to string conversion in
>   U:\XAMPP\htdocs\pds\action\doInsertSchedule.php on line 32

How to show exact result from the query?
Somebody please help.

Comment: Refer here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT TrainingID FROM training ORDER BY TrainingID DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo  " Training ID - " . $row['TrainingID '] .;
      echo "<br>";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
$con = mysql_connect("host_name", "user_name", "password");
mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);
$query="SELECT TrainingID FROM training ORDER BY TrainingID DESC LIMIT 1";
$res=mysql_query($query,$con);
$farow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$answer=$farow['TrainingID'];
```

Comment: Should use msqli instead of mysql.

Comment: @dannmate That's up to _him_

Comment: You shouldn't promote bad practice. The `mysql` library is depricated and as @dannmate said, you should promote `PDO` or `MySQLi`

Comment: it show an error message Undefined index: SubjectTrainingID in U:\XAMPP\htdocs\pds\action\doInsertSchedule.php on line 30